# volatile keyword in java is not visible to other threads below is my code

Tags: java, multithreading

When I update the value of `i` in thread `T1`, the value is not visible to thread `T2` -  why?  Theoretically `volatile` variables must retrieve fresh values, but it is not working.

```
    class Threads implements Runnable
    {

      public volatile int i=4;
      volatile int j=0;
      int x=0;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Threads th=new Threads();
        Thread a = new Thread(th);
        Thread b=new Thread(th);
        a.setName("T1");
        a.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        b.setName("T2");
        a.start();
        b.start();
      }

      public int count() {
        return ++i;
      }

      public void run() {
        while(j<=10)
        {

          if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T1"))
          {
            i++;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" : "+i);

           try
           {
             Thread.sleep(2);
           }catch(Exception ex){}
         }
         else if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("T2"))
         {

           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" : "+i);
           try
           {
             Thread.sleep(1);
           }catch(Exception ex){}
         }

         j++;
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: @Ordous, I'm confused.  The only `i` in the example is a member variable of the `Threads` class.  The example only creates one instance of that class, and the main thread does not seem to use `i`.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes, you are right, misread the code

Comment: What do you expect this program to output?

Comment: "its not working" means ... what?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you expect your code to output, but:

Note that even if a variable is volatile, `x++` is a shortcut for `x = x + 1`. It is not atomic, and performs separate read and write operations, the value may be changed by another thread between the two operations.

In your case, for variable `i`, only one thread is writing the variable, so it should not be an issue.

But for `j`, two threads are doing `j++` on the same variable. There is probability that, for some iterations, one thread writes `j` between the read and write of the other thread. Resulting in the earlier write to be ignored.

to avoid this, you can either:

- do the `j++` in a `synchronized` block
- use `AtomicInteger` instead of `volatile int`

Another point is that the test on `j <= 10` is done before the increment. So the two threads may enter the `while`for an iteration when `j==10`, resulting in the end by having  `j==12` (or even something different when the effect described above is also involved).

To solve that, you may increment directly in the `while` condition, using an `AtomicInteger` for instance:

```
while(j.getAndIncrement() <= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the local i from each thread instance - each of your thread objects has their own i, j , x instances and you are not cross referencing them.

Actually your threads do not even know that there are any other threads out there.

Comment: They use the same Runnable instance...? (Edit: Ninja'd)